# gcc / ld: overlapping sections (.tbss, .init_array) in statically-linked ELF binary

Tags: gcc, ld, static-linking, elf, thread-local-storage

I'm compiling a very simple hello-world one-liner statically on Debian 7 system on x86_64 machine with gcc version 4.8.2 (Debian 4.8.2-21):

```
gcc test.c -static -o test
```

and I get an executable ELF file that includes the following sections:

```
[17] .tdata            PROGBITS         00000000006b4000  000b4000
     0000000000000020  0000000000000000 WAT       0     0     8
[18] .tbss             NOBITS           00000000006b4020  000b4020
     0000000000000030  0000000000000000 WAT       0     0     8
[19] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY       00000000006b4020  000b4020
     0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
[20] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY       00000000006b4030  000b4030
     0000000000000010  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
[21] .jcr              PROGBITS         00000000006b4040  000b4040
     0000000000000008  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     8
[22] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS         00000000006b4060  000b4060
     00000000000000e4  0000000000000000  WA       0     0     32
```

Note that `.tbss` section is allocated at addresses 0x6b4020..0x6b4050 (0x30 bytes) and it intersects with allocation of `.init_array` section at 0x6b4020..0x6b4030 (0x10 bytes), `.fini_array` section at 0x6b4030..0x6b4040 (0x10 bytes) and with `.jcr` section at 0x6b4040..0x6b4048 (8 bytes).

Note it does *not* intersect with the following sections, for example, `.data.rel.ro`, but that's probably because `.data.rel.ro` alignment is 32 and thus it can't be placed any earlier than 0x6b4060.

The resulting file runs ok, but I still don't exactly get how it works. From what I read in glibc documentation, `.tbss` is a just `.bss` section for thread local storage (i.e. allocated memory scratch space, not really mapped in physical file). Is it that `.tbss` section is so special that it can overlap other sections? Are `.init_array`, `.fini_array` and `.jcr` are so useless (for example, they are not needed anymore then TLS-related code runs), so they can be overwritten by bss? Or is it some sort of a bug?

Basically, what do I get to read and write if I'll try to read address 0x6b4020 in my application? `.tbss` contents or `.init_array` pointers? Why?

Comment: Most probably I will NOT help you. But maybe you should read AMD64 gcc ABI reference. http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf. As I remember access to thread local storage is "prefixed" by segment registers FS or GS. If I remember correctly your thread will address FS:0x6b4020.

Comment: Indeed, I remember reading somewhere that it's purely glibc's convention (not platform ABI, not part of SysV calling convention stuff) that thread-local storage would use FS segment prefixed operations... Gonna go and try to read that Drepper's manual on TLS...

Comment: The section is tagged NOBITS, which means there is no data associated with it inside the ELF file, only size. For NOBITS sections, the offset field is filled formally. Another example of such a section is `.bss`, the zero-initialized data section. As long as we know the section is zero-initialized, there is no need to actually store the zeroes in the file, knowing the size is enough.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy: I have no problems with meaningless offset (i.e. 0xb4020), I have problems with overlapping *in-memory* address ranges (i.e. 0x6b4020).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The virtual address of `.tbss` is meaningless as that section only serves as a template for the TLS storage as allocated by the threading implementation in GLIBC.

The way this virtual address comes into place is that `.tbss` follows `.tbdata` in the default linker script:

```
...
.gcc_except_table   : ONLY_IF_RW { *(.gcc_except_table .gcc_except_table.*) }
/* Thread Local Storage sections  */
.tdata          : { *(.tdata .tdata.* .gnu.linkonce.td.*) }
.tbss           : { *(.tbss .tbss.* .gnu.linkonce.tb.*) *(.tcommon) }
.preinit_array     :
{
  PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
  KEEP (*(.preinit_array))
  PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
}
.init_array     :
{
   PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
   KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
   KEEP (*(.init_array))
   PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
}
...
```

therefore its virtual address is simply the virtual address of the preceding section (`.tbdata`) plus the size of the preceding section (eventually with some padding in order to reach the desired alignment). `.init_array` (or `.preinit_array` if present) comes next and its location should be determined the same way, but `.tbss` is known to be so very special, that it is given a deeply hard-coded treatment inside GNU LD:

```
/* .tbss sections effectively have zero size.  */
if ((os->bfd_section->flags & SEC_HAS_CONTENTS) != 0
    || (os->bfd_section->flags & SEC_THREAD_LOCAL) == 0
    || link_info.relocatable)
  dotdelta = TO_ADDR (os->bfd_section->size);
else
  dotdelta = 0;    // <----------------
dot += dotdelta;
```

`.tbss` is not relocatable, it has the `SEC_THREAD_LOCAL` flag set, and it does not have contents (`NOBITS`), therefore the `else` branch is taken. In other words, no matter how large the `.tbss` is, the linker does not advance the location of the section that follows it (also know as "the dot").

Note also that `.tbss` sits in a non-loadable ELF segment:

```
Program Headers:
  Type           Offset             VirtAddr           PhysAddr
                 FileSiz            MemSiz              Flags  Align
  LOAD           0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000
                 0x00000000000b1f24 0x00000000000b1f24  R E    200000
  LOAD           0x00000000000b2000 0x00000000006b2000 0x00000000006b2000
                 0x0000000000002288 0x00000000000174d8  RW     200000
  NOTE           0x0000000000000158 0x0000000000400158 0x0000000000400158
                 0x0000000000000044 0x0000000000000044  R      4
  TLS            0x00000000000b2000 0x00000000006b2000 0x00000000006b2000 <---+
                 0x0000000000000020 0x0000000000000060  R      8              |
  GNU_STACK      0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000     |
                 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000  RW     8              |
                                                                              |
 Section to Segment mapping:                                                  |
  Segment Sections...                                                         |
   00     .note.ABI-tag ...                                                   |
   01     .tdata .ctors ...                                                   |
   02     .note.ABI-tag ...                                                   |
   03     .tdata .tbss    <---------------------------------------------------+
   04
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for - `SEC_THREAD_LOCAL` flag is what makes this section special (*not* a `.tbss` name - in fact, it can have any name). Clear and concise answer. Sorry for being late with bounty...

Comment: Would you happen to know how to get the size of the tbss and put it in a variable? I'm compiling with `-static -nostdlib` and I have a few `__thread` variables. I have 0 idea how much memory I need to allocate so I was wondering if there's a way my code can get the value at runtime. Does the linker put it in a variable somewhere? Can I put a label before and after the tbss section to figure the size out (len = labelAfterTBSS - labelBeforeTBBS). What can I do? I tried asking but got no answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69498912/how-do-i-setup-thread-when-i-use-static-nostdlib

Comment: @EricStotch I don't think the linker adds any variables holding section information to the final executable. And you will have hard time telling the compiler to fix the order of variables in `.tbss`. Your best bet is parsing the ELF file structure, e.g., by using the [section-related functions of the BFD library](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.37/bfd/section-prototypes.html#bfd_005fget_005fsection_005fby_005fname).

Answer (score 2):

This is rather simple if you have an understanding about two things:

1) What is SHT_NOBITS

2) What is tbss section

SHT_NOBITS means that this section occupies no space inside file.

Normally, NOBITS sections, like bss are placed **after** all PROGBITS sections at the end of the loaded segments.

tbss is special section to hold uninitialized thread-local data that contribute to the program's memory image. Take an attention here: this section must hold unique data for each program thread.

Now lets talk about overlapping. We have two possible overlappings -- inside binary file and inside memory.

1) Binary files offset:

There is no data to write under this section in binary. Inside file it holds no space, so linker start next section init_array immediately after tbss declared. You may think about its size not as about size, but as about special service information for code like:

```
if (isTLSSegment) tlsStartAddr += section->memSize();
```

So it doesn't overlap anything inside file.

2) Memory offset

The tdata and tbss sections may be possibly modified at startup time by the dynamic linker
performing relocations, but after that the section data is kept around as the **initialization image** and not modified anymore. For each thread, including the initial one, new memory is allocated into which then the content of the initialization image is copied. This ensures that all threads get the same starting conditions.

This what makes tbss (and tdata) so special.

Do not think about their memory offsets as about statically known -- they are more like "generation patterns" for per-thread work. So they also can not overlap with "normal" memory offsets -- they are being processed in other way.

You may consult with [this paper](http://dev.gentoo.org/~dberkholz/articles/toolchain/tls.pdf) to know more.

Comment: I'm not complaining about file offsets, I'm complaining about overlapping flat memory addresses. Namely, `.tbss` intersects with `.init_array`, `.fini_array` and `.jcr`. You've mentioned that `.tbss` section is "special" - why is it so? Is it determined by name (`.tbss`)? If so, are there any other such "special" sections? Who determines what would be ultimately mapped to 0x6b4020?

Comment: Expanded answer to cover memory offsets, added reference link