# section .tbss mismatches non-TLS reference in

Tags: c++, gcc

When I'm compiling my software on ubuntu 16.04, the compilation completed successfully.

When I'm trying to compile it on kubuntu 14.04, I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: _ZN3NTL8ZZ_pInfoE: TLS definition in /home/user/libscapi/install/lib/libntl.a(ZZ_p.o) section .tbss mismatches non-TLS reference in CMakeFiles/LWEBasedMPC.dir/src/Party.cpp.o
/home/user/libscapi/install/lib/libntl.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
```

I looked at [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25760908/4193208) and try to compile the NTL library on the kubuntu, but the error is still exists.

I'm using gcc-5.2.1 on kubuntu and gcc-5.4.1 on ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaration of `ZZ_pInfo` used during compilation of Party.cpp.o is incompatible with definition in libntl.a. One common reason for this is that `-I` and `-L` are broken i.e. point t different, incompatible versions of library. Can you ensure that your `CXXFLAGS` include `/home/user/libscapi/install/include`?